# strange condition file not found nginx with php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I was working with this config from 2 years without any problem

sudenly I face not found error message from niginx

and its come only when the link has "?"
sample

```
domain/index.php?a=browse&b=category&id=1
```

if open the normal link, its working (without "php?")

```
domain/index.php
domain/[any other php file].php
```

site config (changed user info)

```
server {
listen *:80;
server_name  domain;
rewrite_log on;
            root   /home/user/public_html/;

location / {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm ;
    }

     location ~*^.+\.jpg|jpeg|gif|css|html|png|js|ico|bmp|zip|rar|txt|pdf|doc)$ {
            root /home/user/public_html/;
            # expires max;
            access_log off;
    }


location ~ ^/.+\.php {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;


    }


}
```

Comment: i can't yet understand your problem?

Comment: It seems args aren't being passed in the nginx config, something along the lines `location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}`

Comment: shrotly this link only work domain.com/index.php or domain.com/browse.php and this not working give not found error domain.com/index.php?id=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use ip  change it  from

```
server_name  domain;
```

to

```
server_name  serverip;
```

and test url

```
serverip/index.php?a=browse&b=category&id=1
```

you can check it else with ssh comand

```
wget localhost/index.php?a=browse&b=category&id=1
```

if work , check any firewall or any services like cloudflare

Comment: you are really amazing, its fix the problem, the problem was in cloudflare can't accept the request when link has dynamic request, spend lot of hours and you find the solution. thanks again.